# How to show/hide in javascript when function unhides 2 elements?

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

i have a javascript to hide/unhide 2 elements in my html at the same time. It worked fine when it was only one but now for some reason some elements only dissapear when i click twice, i dont know where is the mistake, here's the code in case anyone finds something wrong thanks.
The function unhides two elements whos div id's are given (xdivID and divID) and keeps the parent and the grandparent visible (idParent idUncle)

```
function doubleunhide(xdivID, divID, idParent, idUncle) {
 var xitem = document.getElementById(xdivID);
 if(xitem){
 xitem.className='unhidden';
}
var item = document.getElementById(divID);
 if(item) {
   item.className='unhidden';
   }
   var elements = getElementsByClassName(document, "unhidden");
      var n = elements.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     var e = elements[i];
if ((e.id != divID) && (e.id != xdivID) && (e.id != idParent) && (e.id != idUncle)){
     e.className='hidden';
     }
  }}
```

And here's how it is implemented in the html:

```
<div id="prj" class="hidden" style="margin-left:1em">
    <a href="javascript:doubleunhide('prj011', 'prj01numbers', 'prj', 'nil');" style="text-decoration:none; color: rgb(0,0,0)" id="prj01link">Project 01</a> <br>
    <a href="javascript:doubleunhide('prj021', 'prj02numbers', 'prj', 'nil');" style="text-decoration:none; color: rgb(0,0,0)" id="prj02link">Project 02</a> <br>
    <a href="javascript:doubleunhide('prj031', 'prj03numbers', 'prj', 'nil');" style="text-decoration:none; color: rgb(0,0,0)" id="prj03link">Project 03</a> <br>
    Project 04<br>
    Project 05<br>
    </div>
```

Comment: It would help if you make a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Where are you extending getElementsByClassName() from? This isn't a standard method.

Comment: What CSS is associated with `unhidden` and `hidden` classes?

Comment: yes, i copied from another post, it works fine when i only unhide one element at a time.. im preparing a short jsfiddle...

Comment: Here's a link to the funny behaviour [link] (http://www.417i.com/HdM/) i have shortened the html as much as possible to make it more readible without disabling the error

Comment: As for instance it also works fine when there's only project01, but with both project 01 and project 02 it starts to get messy

Comment: Change `getElementsByClassName(document, "unhidden")` to `getElementsByClassName("unhidden")`

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for the tip though i think that if i do that i would limit the code to use the native implementation of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that then you use native `node.getElementsByClassName()` the resulting array is 'live' - it changes dynamically then you change page. In your case - then you execute `e.className='hidden';` the `elements` array is changed and becomes smaller - current element are wiped out because it is no loger fit your search criteria what you passed in to `getElementsByClassName()`. But your code still thinks there is same elements and iterate over it. You trying get undefined node eventually, get errors and script broke.
To avoid this you can iterate in reverse order:

```
   for (var i = n-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
     var e = elements[i];
     if ((e.id != divID) && (e.id != xdivID) && (e.id != idParent) && (e.id != idUncle)){
         e.className='hidden';
     }
```